# Run macro on cell change using a case

Tags: vba, excel

I am sure that this is a simple answer, but I am unfamiliar with cases in VBA. What I am trying to do is create a case that monitors specific cells for changes.

If a change to the specified range occurs, then some macro should run as a response to that change. Else, nothing should happen. Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case (Change)
        Case Range("A1").Address
            Call success
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
Sub success()
' success Macro
Cells(1, 10).Value = "Success!"
End Sub
```

Problem is that nothing seems to happen. Mind you, this is just a test to understand cases, etc. Once I am provided with a solution I hope to expand this to something more intricate.

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the "Select Case (Change)" portion of the code, but I am unsure. Please don't respond to this question using an if/else statement, I would really like it in the form of a case. Thanks!

Comment: Try `Select Case Target.Address ... Case "$A$1" .. ` to test for a specific cell location.

Comment: What is in the variable `Change`? I have assumed in my previous comment that you would want to test the address of `Target` but perhaps not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
    Case "A1": Call success
    Case "A2": Call DoSomething
    Case Else: Call OtherAction
End Select
```

**NOTE**
The `Target` parameter:

1. Can be several cells (or whole column or row)
2. Can contain non-contiguous ranges (in this case, you need to traverse Areas property to get those ranges)

Comment: It should be noted that Target could be more tan a single cell.

Comment: Very concise and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeeped Added explanation

Comment: It also should be noted that the event fires again if one of the macros success, DoSomething or OtherAction changes A1 or A2

Comment: @Storax What else should be noted? Perhaps, I forgot to include error handler and switch off DisplayAlerts, EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating, set calculation to manual? You add.

Comment: As written, If one of the macros changes A1 or A2 the event will fire again. You have to take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

A conciser example would look like that

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const CELL1 = "A1"
Const CELL2 = "C2"
Const CELL3 = "D3"

Dim rg As Range

On Error GoTo ExitSub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set rg = Union(Range(CELL1), Range(CELL2), Range(CELL3))

    If Intersect(rg, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' Do nothing
    Else
        Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
        Case CELL1
            Call success(1)
        Case CELL2
            Call success(2)
        Case CELL3
            Call success(3)
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
        End Select
    End If

ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub success(i As Long)
' success Macro
    Cells(i, 10).Value = "Success!"
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to remove *Selection* from *Worksheet_SelectionChange*.